# Fluent NHibernate - One to many mapping without primary keys in database

Tags: primary-key, one-to-many, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

In my database I have table A with primary key IdA and a table B without primary key and with columns IdA (foreign key to A) and IdB (simple column, not a primary key). In code Class A must have a collection of B instances.

Can you please tell me how to create the HasMany mapping in A's classmap? I have tried all sorts of ways and keep receiving errors from NHibernate...missing getter properties, cannot insert null into db columns etc.

edit: after adding a composite key on a test version of this db I get a different error, "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1"

Comment: Why doesn't `Table B` have a primary key? Any table **ought to have** a way to uniquely and reliably identify each row - a **primary key**

Comment: Maybe size constraint issues? Well in theory a row in table B is identified by IdA and IdB, so in code I was using CompositeId().KeyProperty..........

Comment: I temporarily added a composite key